# Descartes' rule of signs

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I am trying to find a polynomial where for example the sign alternate 4 times but where there are only 2 positive real roots and where the remaining roots are negative real roots. The fact is that it is very easy to find a polynomial where the sign for instance alternate 3 times and where there are exactly 3 positive real roots. My problem is to find a polynomial which for instance alternate 4 times but where there are less than 4 positive real roots.

I hope it makes sense. Otherwise I would very much like to explain it further

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example $\,P(x) = (x^2+1)(x^2-ax+1) = x^4 - a x^3 + 2 x^2 - a x + 1\,$:

- for $\,a \gt 0\,$ it has $4$ sign changes;
- for $\,a \in (0,2)\,$ it has no real roots;
- for $\,a \ge 2\,$ it has two positive real roots.

$P(x^2)\,$ has the same number of sign changes as $\,P(x)\,$, so for $\,a \ge 2\,$ it has two positive and two negative real roots.

---

[ *EDIT* ] Additional note about this part of the question.

> find a polynomial where for example the sign alternate 4 times but where there are only 2 positive real roots and where the remaining roots are negative real roots

No such polynomial exists. If the number of positive real roots is strictly less than the number of sign changes then the roots cannot be all real.

This follows from the complete statement of Descartes' rule of signs, as found for example at $§2.1$ and $§2.3.1$ in [Historical account and ultra-simple proofs of Descartes's rule of signs, De Gua, Fourier, and Budan's rule](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6664).

Intuition in the simpler case of a polynomial with all coefficients non-zero is that the number of sign changes $\,n^+,n^-\,$ in the coefficients of $\,P(x), P(-x)\,$ adds up to $\,n=\text{deg}\, P$ since $\,P(-x)\,$ flips the sign of every other coefficient. If $\,n^+=4\,$ then $\,n^-=n-4\,$, so the number of negative roots is at most $\,n-4\,$. Since there are only two positive roots, there are at most $\,2+(n-4)$ $=n-2\,$ real roots, so at least two roots must be non-real complex.

Comment: Thank you! In relation to this I have a question. 
the following polynomial f(x)=x^5 - 3*x^4 + 3*x^3 - 9*x^2 - 4*x + 12. In f(x) there is  4 sign changes so according to Descartes lemma there exists 4, 2 or 0 positive real roots right? And by looking at f(-x) I observe one sign change. Does this mean that there is exactly one negative real root? It is right to conclude that there is 4 sign changes in f(x) but only 2 positive real roots, and 1 sign change in f(-x) which means exactly one negative root. The remaining roots are complex.

Comment: The thing is that I need to make a assignment where a student can discover Descartes rule of sign

Comment: @Sumi Right, your $f(x)$ has one negative root and $4,2$ or $0$ positive roots - though it is not possible to tell how many by the rule of signs alone.

Comment: There is four sign changes in f(x) which means that there can maximal be four positive real roots right?  or does the sign lemma says that because there is four sign changes in f(x) there is four positive roots, but we dont know whether these roots are real or complex?

Comment: @Sumi "Positive" is shorthand for "positive real" since complex numbers don't have an order or a sign. In this case, the rule of signs says there are $4,2$ or $0$ positive real roots.